# side menu Help 2

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

I'm trying to use tableviewcotroller with this but when look at the screenshot at the button will seen a issue I need helping fixing so if anyone knows how to fix this plz help I don't want use SWRevealViewController I'm also doing with all code not scoreboards thanks for the help

```
class SidebarView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var titleArr = [String]()

    weak var delegate: SidebarViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.clipsToBounds=true

        titleArr = ["Brittney Atwood", "Messages", "Contact", "Settings", "History", "Help", "Sign Out"]

        setupViews()

        myTableView.delegate=self
        myTableView.dataSource=self
        myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        myTableView.tableFooterView=UIView()
        myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
        myTableView.allowsSelection = true
        myTableView.bounces=false
        myTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=false
        myTableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rectangle 96"))
        myTableView.isOpaque = false

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titleArr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cellImg: UIImageView!
            cellImg = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 10, width: 80, height: 80))
            cellImg.layer.cornerRadius = 40
            cellImg.layer.masksToBounds=true
            cellImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            cellImg.layer.masksToBounds=true
            cellImg.image=#imageLiteral(resourceName: "user11")
            cell.addSubview(cellImg)

            let cellLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 110, y: cell.frame.height/2-15, width: 250, height: 30))
            cell.addSubview(cellLbl)
            cellLbl.text = titleArr[indexPath.row]
            cellLbl.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
            cellLbl.textColor=UIColor.white
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text=titleArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.textColor=UIColor.white
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.delegate?.sidebarDidSelectRow(row: Row(row: indexPath.row))
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return 100
        } else {
            return 60
        }
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.addSubview(myTableView)
        myTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive=true
        myTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive=true
        myTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive=true
        myTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive=true
    }

    let myTableView: UITableView = {
        let table=UITableView()
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        return table
    }()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I make a demo project

Comment: This line of code most probably creates that empty view in the tableView footer:

    myTableView.tableFooterView=UIView()

Try removing it.

Comment: one sec I will let you know

Comment: nope did't work

Answer (score 0):

Please write this code it may helps to you.

```
        var topSafeArea: CGFloat
        var bottomSafeArea: CGFloat

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            topSafeArea = view.safeAreaInsets.top
            bottomSafeArea = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else {
            topSafeArea = topLayoutGuide.length
            bottomSafeArea = bottomLayoutGuide.length
        }

        // safe area values are now available to use
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

that the view controller I don’t know where the issue is it probably in one of the two files that I post it still not fix

```
 class ViewController: UITableViewController {
 var sidebarView: SidebarView!
 var blackScreen: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Messages"

    let btnMenu = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(btnMenuAction))
    btnMenu.tintColor=UIColor(red: 54/255, green: 55/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnMenu

    sidebarView=SidebarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: self.view.frame.height))
    sidebarView.delegate=self
    sidebarView.layer.zPosition=100
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(sidebarView)

    blackScreen=UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    blackScreen.backgroundColor=UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    blackScreen.isHidden=true
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(blackScreen)
    blackScreen.layer.zPosition=99
    let tapGestRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(blackScreenTapAction(sender:)))
    blackScreen.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestRecognizer)
}

@objc func btnMenuAction() {
    blackScreen.isHidden=false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.sidebarView.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: self.sidebarView.frame.height)
    }) { (complete) in
        self.blackScreen.frame=CGRect(x: self.sidebarView.frame.width, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width-self.sidebarView.frame.width, height: self.view.bounds.height+100)
    }
}

@objc func blackScreenTapAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    blackScreen.isHidden=true
    blackScreen.frame=self.view.bounds
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.sidebarView.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: self.sidebarView.frame.height)
    }
  }  
}

extension ViewController: SidebarViewDelegate {
func sidebarDidSelectRow(row: Row) {
    blackScreen.isHidden=true
    blackScreen.frame=self.view.bounds
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.sidebarView.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: self.sidebarView.frame.height)
    }
    switch row {
    case .editProfile:
        let vc=EditProfileVC()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    case .messages:
        print("Messages")
    case .contact:
        print("Contact")
    case .settings:
        print("Settings")
    case .history:
        print("History")
    case .help:
        print("Help")
    case .signOut:
        print("Sign out")
    case .none:
        break
        //        default:  //Default will never be executed
        //            break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain in answer what you change in code so, issue that you face is solve ? you only write **that the view controller** the reader can not understand what is issue which resolve in above answer.

Comment: This code works fine in a uiviewcontroller but I still get the issue in a uitableviewcontroller and I need the uitableviewcontroller

Comment: what you use in background for side menu? that is imageview ? in which white portion is show at bottom.

Comment: I don't fellow what you are saying